# How to Join data from one column from two rows in SQL Server and place value in a second column

Tags: sql-server, merge

```
SELECT 
    staffclass.[Class_DBID],
    [Course_DBID],
    [DistrictClassID],
    [SectionDescr],
    [HomePageURL],
    [AvgCalcCd],
    staffclass.Staff_DBID,
    staff.DistrictStaffID,
    staffclass.RoleCd,
    [Scale_DBID]
FROM
    [studentsys].[dbo].[Class]
INNER JOIN 
    staffclass ON staffclass.Class_DBID = Class.Class_DBID
INNER JOIN 
    staff ON staff.staff_dbid = staffclass.Staff_dbid
INNER JOIN 
    school ON school.School_DBID = staff.school_dbid
WHERE 
    DistrictClassID = 'ONMS03712'
```

[image]

I need to take the data where the Class_DBID match and generate one row where the DistrictStaffID value is in 'Teacher1' Column for RoleCd 'P' (Primary) and 'Teacher2', 'Teacher3', 'Teacher4' for any RoleCd = 'A' for (Additional).

[image]

[image: Example of output needed]

Comment: What's wrong with conditional aggregation? Generate a `ROW_NUMBER` and group, selecting `MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN DistrictStaffId END)` etc

Comment: So I am grouping by Class_DBID and selecting when row number > 1 I see you have = in your example but that wouldn't put them together?

Comment: You will be "ruined" with your inconsistent coding and the mixture of three-part names and one-part names. Do schema-qualify objects names as that is a best practice. Don't use three-part names as that makes your code more fragile and impossible to move to different databases without additional work. Give every table an alias and use the correct alias for every column reference - another best practice. And generally order of rows matters so an ORDER BY clause is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a row-number, then use conditional aggregation over that

```sql
SELECT 
    staffclass.[Class_DBID],
    [Course_DBID],
    [DistrictClassID],
    [SectionDescr],
    [HomePageURL],
    [AvgCalcCd],
    Staff_DBID  = MIN(CASE WHEN staff.RoleCd = 'P' THEN staff.Staff_DBID END),
    Teacher1 = MIN(CASE WHEN staff.rn = 1 THEN staff.DistrictStaffID END),
    Teacher2 = MIN(CASE WHEN staff.rn = 2 THEN staff.DistrictStaffID END),
    Teacher3 = MIN(CASE WHEN staff.rn = 3 THEN staff.DistrictStaffID END),
    Teacher4 = MIN(CASE WHEN staff.rn = 4 THEN staff.DistrictStaffID END)
FROM
    [studentsys].[dbo].[Class]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        staff.staff_dbid,
        staff.DistrictStaffID,
        staffclass.RoleCd,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY staffclass.staff_dbid ORDER BY CASE WHEN staffclass.RoleCd = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
    FROM
        staffclass
    INNER JOIN 
        staff ON staff.staff_dbid = staffclass.Staff_dbid
) staff ON staff.Class_DBID = Class.Class_DBID
INNER JOIN
    school ON school.School_DBID = staff.school_dbid
WHERE 
    DistrictClassID = 'ONMS03712'
GROUP BY
    Class.Class_DBID,
    [Course_DBID],
    [DistrictClassID],
    [SectionDescr],
    [HomePageURL],
    [AvgCalcCd];
```